# Catching MatchError at val initialisation with pattern matching in Scala?

Tags: scala

What is the best way (concisest, clearest, idiomatic) to catch a `MatchError`, when assigning values with pattern matching?

Example:

```
val a :: b :: Nil = List(1,2,3) // throws scala.MatchError
```

The best way I found so far:

```
val a :: b :: Nil = try {
    val a1 :: b1 :: Nil = List(1,2,3)
    List(a1, b1)
  catch { case e:MatchError => // handle error here }
```

Is there an idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: You could also use `scala.util.control.Exception`.

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Comment: Isn't a `MatchError` exactly the thing you *want* to throw if a pattern match assignment fails? Otherwise I would personally use other control constructs to handle the problem differently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Slightly improving on Kim's solution:

```
val a :: b :: Nil = List(1, 2, 3) match {
  case x @ _ :: _ :: Nil => x
  case _ => //handle error
}
```

If you could provide more information on how you might handle the error, we could provide you a better solution.

Comment: About handling - probably just throwing an appropriate exception.

Answer (score 7):

Why not simply

```
val a::b::Nil = List(1,2,3) match {
  case a1::b1::Nil => {
    a1::b1::Nil
  }
  case _ => //handle error
}
```

?

Comment: That's still 4 lines long and it would have ridiculous code reduplication in complex pattern matches.

Comment: In complex pattern matches, using multiple assignments with exceptions will be a real mess. Kim's answer is th emost idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

The following doesn't catch the error but avoids (some of; see Nicolas' comment) it. I don't know whether this is interesting to the asker.

```
scala> val a :: b :: _ = List(1,2,3)
a: Int = 1
b: Int = 2
```

Comment: It doesn't avoid anything if you have less than 2 elements.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is this:

```
List(1, 2, 3) match {
   case a :: b :: Nil => .....
   case _ => // handle error
}
```

I don't like to match twice, because it is redundant.
The "val" with pattern matching should only be used when you are sure it matches, or add a try /catch block.